# Is it possible to read FB page ratings server-side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to create ratings grabber from my Facebook fanpage. It can by PHP, Python or Ruby code fired once a day by cron.

I've created an FB_APP so I get APP_ID, APP_SECRET and CLIENT_TOKEN.

When I use Graph API Explorer, there is a access_token which I can use to temporary call to API. Using generated USER_ACCES_TOKEN I can get PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN by call

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/accounts
```

then grab page and token

To get ratings I use

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{page_id}/ratings?fields=review_text,reviewer&access_token=xxxx
```

Parameter access_token is a PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN.

Is it possible to get USER_ACCES_TOKEN or PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN server-side only without show user login dialog? My script should download ratings without any user attention.

I tried to use OAuth APP_ACCESS_TOKEN, but it is not permitted to access pages.

Comment: No, getting the initial user access token always requires user interaction in some form.

Comment: So, I should prepare some "admin panel" where put FB login for fanpage administrator then get USER_ACCES_TOKEN and grab ratings? What about long expire TOKENS? Can I use it and reset in "admin panel" after expire?

Comment: It's only getting the initial user access token that requires user interaction. Afterwards if you have any form of storage you could store your token there, use it in your script and also refresh it periodically, all without user interaction.